# Error at getPackageName() in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sms

To send Image through SMS in phonegap, following this tutorial http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/social-share-plugin-for-android-cordova-2-2-0-email-sms-facebook-twitter-share/ in phonegap
the code should be given like this

```
    uris.add(Uri.parse(“android.resource://” + getPackageName() + “/” + R.drawable.file1));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris));
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

But here I dont know what to give in the place of

> getPackageName()

Here I have placed my package name as

```
             uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + com.sarathdr.plugins.SocialShare() + "/" R.drawable.background));
```

com.sarathdr.plugins cannot be resolved to a type  please anybody help me.

Comment: Why don't you use `getPackageName()`?  Even if you don't, what does your `SocialShare()` method return?

Comment: Because its not a method. Write package name as a String. Like,  `"com.sarathdr.plugins.SocialShare"`. remove  `()` from it

Comment: thanks for your reply even at R.drawable i get error as Syntax error on token "R", delete this token and drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field, how do i solve this? @user370305

Comment: Where are you writing the code in Activity Class??

Comment: yes, but there is no onCreate method here because this is one activity in phonegap @user370305

Comment: Ok Using Context of the Activity you can access Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.file1));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris));
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

the packageName is an identifier of your app which defined in AndroidManifest.xml. I think it may be 'com.sarathdr.plugins' in your app, you can have a check.

Answer (score 0):

Check this may be this plugin is easy to integrate .. [Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/EmailComposerWithAttachments)